# exchange powershell : get-mailbox outside default scope

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

how do you run the cmdlet "get-mailbox" outside the current default scope of the current domain?

When I run get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit bob.com/bobsage
I get an error message saying:
Get-mailbox: The requested search root 'rss.com/rsstoilet' is not in the current default scope 'ens.com'. Cannot perform searches outside the current default scope.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set this global variable:

`$AdminSessionADSettings.ViewEntireForest = $True`

Or use `Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $True`

Or set it on a cmdlet level:

`Get-Mailbox -IgnoreDefaultScope`

Comment: will i have to set this variable every time i run the script?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error message is accurate - it *cannot* perform searches outside the current default scope. You would need to change the scope you're running the command in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the second option(-ignoredefaultscope), make sure to pass the DN of the object as a parameter to -Identity.

ex: Get-Mailbox -IgnoreDefaultScope -Identity "cn=username,ou=ouname,dc=domainname,dc=com"

Thanks,
Sitaram Pamarthi

[www.techibee.com](http://techibee.com)